# How do I change the priority of a process/program

Tags: system-monitor

I would like to be able to change the priority of the SuperTuxKart process to a higher one so that it will run with less lag. It is quite easy to do on Windows (you just need the administrator password/account) but it's basically impossible in Ubuntu.
 I tried `gksu gnome-system-monitor` and `sudo gnome-system-monitor` but both gave me processes for the root account, not mine (an administrator account).

Any help I can get is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## changing a process' priority...

### from the gui:

Run the system monitor as root with

```
gksu gnome-system-monitor
```

Then under the "view" menu move the radio button to "All processes"

[image: enter code here]

Then you will see all users processes and can change their priority.

### from the command line:

First find your processes PID (Process ID) with `pidof`  like so:

```
pidof name-of-process
```

It will return the PID of the given process, usually a four to five character number.  Then run

```
renice priority processes-PID
```

Replacing `priority` with the priority you want (`-20` being the highest and `+20` being the lowest) and `process-PID` with the PID you got earlier.

`renice` is used to change the priority of a *running* process, if you want to start a process *and* change it's priority you use `nice`.

```
nice priority name-of-process
```

Replacing `priority` with the priority you want and `name-of-process` with the name of the process you want to start.

*Note:*  In order to give a process a negative priority you must have root access.

Comment: Doesn't do anything, though. CFS semantics mean you can't renice. Nice has nothing to do with it anymore. Don't think so? Run prime95 with the memory limit set really low, so it is just a regular program that uses 100% on each cpu. Now play a youtube video on 1080p. Pauses right? Prime95 is Low priority. Now multiselect all the chrome processes and make them High. The skipping continues. It has no effect. If you push back on prime95, just install `stress` and `stress -c $(nproc)` and it will spam sqrt.

Answer (score 2):

When you have opened the System Monitor with gksu, you can set it to show processes from all users by selecting **"View -> All Processes"**.

After that, you should see your own processes as well as the system processes. Editing their priority should work fine as well.